# How to use Custom Event (not Event Emitter) without `strictTemplates` to complain about `$event` not being a Custom Event type?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-slickgrid

I created an Angular library, named [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid), which is a wrapper of SlickGrid which is an old JavaScript/jQuery library and I can use any of the Custom Event sent by SlickGrid without any issues as shown below (at this point all is good)

```html
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid28"
    [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [dataset]="dataset"                    
    (onSelectedRowsChanged)="handleOnSelectedRowsChanged($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)">
</angular-slickgrid>
```

and everything is good and it all works

```js
handleOnSelectedRowsChanged(event: any, args: OnSelectedRowsChangedEventArgs) {
    console.log(args);
}
```

in my lib, I simply dispatch these events with a small function that has the following code

```js
/** Dispatch of Custom Event, which by default will bubble & is cancelable */
dispatchCustomEvent(eventName: string, data?: any, isBubbling: boolean = true, isCancelable: boolean = true) {
  const eventInit: CustomEventInit = { bubbles: isBubbling, cancelable: isCancelable };
  if (data) {
    eventInit.detail = data;
  }
  return this.elm.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventName, eventInit));
}
```

Everything is great and life is beautiful...

##### It breaks when enabling `strictTemplates`

When I decided to enable the `strictTemplates` into the [angularCompilerOptions](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options) that is when Angular started complaining about `$event` being a type `Event` and it complains that `detail` is not a valid property BUT in my implementation it's not of type `Event`, it should be detected as type `CustomEvent`.

Why is Angular not detecting it as a `CustomEvent`? Are there any ways of enforcing the type to be detected as `CustomEvent` or overriding the type to be `CustomEvent` without Angular complaining?

The only (ugly) way I found so far to bypass these errors is to make it think that it's a type `Event` but then cast it back to `CustomEvent` and this works but it adds so much code which is inconvenient

```html
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid28"
    [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [dataset]="dataset"                    
    (onSelectedRowsChanged)="handleOnSelectedRowsChanged($event)">
</angular-slickgrid>
```

and then cast the `Event` to `CustomEvent` and even though this works it adds so much code which is inconvenient

```js
handleOnSelectedRowsChanged(event: Event) {
    const args = (event as CustomEvent).detail.args as OnSelectedRowsChangedEventArgs;
    console.log(args);
}
```

I don't want and cannot use Event Emitter because these events are dynamics and because these events are coming from a JavaScript library, there are also other technical reasons but again I cannot use Event Emitter.

[image]

Would that be fixable via an Angular Directive? I've seen this other SO [Angular 4 trigger custom event - EventEmitter vs dispatchEvent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194485/angular-4-trigger-custom-event-eventemitter-vs-dispatchevent) which kinda go in that route but I'm still unsure on what to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [$any()](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid.git) function to disable type checking for **$event** might get around this error.

```html
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid28"
    [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [dataset]="dataset"                    
    (onSelectedRowsChanged)="handleOnSelectedRowsChanged($any($event))">
</angular-slickgrid>
```

Comment: hmm ok but that is just a patch and isn't much better than doing `(event as CustomEvent)` or just slightly less to code. I would rather find a real fix if possible instead of just silencing the issue

Comment: also I assume your answer is partially wrong and should instead be `handleOnSelectedRowsChanged($any($event).detail.eventData, $any($event).detail.args)` to align my original issue shown on top