# angular-slickgrid gettting Property 'detail' does not exist on type 'Event' on angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

I'm working with angular-slickgrid v6 in angular 16.While using `(onClick)="onCellClicked($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)"` to fetch the selected row,I get this error `Property 'detail' does not exist on type 'Event'. (onClick)="onCellClicked($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)"` .Now how to get the selected row ? Below I'm attaching my code:
html file:

```
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1"
                     [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
                     [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                     [dataset]="dataset"
                     (onClick)="onCellClicked($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)"
                      >
  </angular-slickgrid>
```

Now adding typescript file:

```
 this.gridOptions = {
  enableAutoResize: false,
  enableSorting: true,
  gridHeight: 400,
  gridWidth: 1500,
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableExcelExport: true, registerExternalResources: [new ExcelExportService()]
};
onCellClicked(e:any,args:any) {
// let row=args.item;
// console.log(e.detail.args.grid.getData())
// console.log(e.detail.eventData)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably have `strictTemplates` enabled (which is enabled by default when creating a new project from the CLI) and this is causing issues in Angular-Slickgrid because all the SlickGrid and Angular-Slickgrid events are Custom Event which Angular complains about because it doesn't find its types, this is extensively discussed in this Angular-Slickgrid discussion [Template error](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/discussions/815) and I also opened a Stack Overflow question on that matter as well.
[How to use Custom Event (not Event Emitter) without `strictTemplates` to complain about `$event` not being a Custom Event type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68490848/how-to-use-custom-event-not-event-emitter-without-stricttemplates-to-complai)

Also see Angular [type checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck) docs

You have 3 approaches to deal with this

1. disabled `strictTemplates` in your `tsconfig.json` config
2. cast the event in the template to `$any` type

- `$any($event)` for example `$any($event).detail.eventData`

```html
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1"
  (onClick)="onCellClicked($any($event))"
</angular-slickgrid>
```

3. cast the event in the ViewModel component to `CustomEvent`

```html
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1"
  (onClick)="onCellClicked($event)"
</angular-slickgrid>
```

```js
onCellClicked(e: CustomEvent) {
 const { eventData, args } = (event as CustomEvent).detail as any;
}

// or simply
onCellClicked(e: any) {
 const eventData = event.detail.eventData;
}
```

The simplest is obviously the option 1 but you lose the strictness on the view templates (which personally I don't care that much and I usually disable it myself).

I added a [Troubleshooting Section](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid#stricttemplates-error) on the Angular-Slickgrid readme.

It was also explained in the [On Events - Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid/wiki/Grid-&-DataView-Events#error-thrown-in-the-ide-when-using-stricttemplates)

Comment: the issue has gone but `onCellClicked(e, args) {
    console.log(args.item)
  }   ` it prints undefined.How to get the selected data? The html : `(onClick)="onCellClicked($any($event).detail.eventData, $any($event).detail.args)" `

Comment: it should be `args.dataContext` and you can see that in [Example 22](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/angular-components) with the same `onClick` event and a console log of its `args`